# Can I bind action to a keypress in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I have `(kbd "C-c S-<down>")` and `(kbd "C-c S-<up>")` bound to `shrink-window` and `enlarge-window`, respectively.

It works, but I also want Emacs to change window size during a keypress, while I am holding `S-<down>` or `S-<up>`.

Is it possible in Emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(define-key global-map [S-up] 'enlarge-window)

(define-key global-map [S-down] 'shrink-window)
```